# what to do with timers when replacing a scene?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

after so much reading, i can see there is so much miss understanding on what should i do when replacing scene.
on the dealloc method, do i have to release ALL my timers ?? or cocos2d does it ??

i have 3 timers on startup:

```
[self schedule: @selector(contact:)];
[self schedule:@selector(tick:)]; 
[self schedule: @selector(randomsActions:) interval:0.1];
```

befor i replace the scene to menu (replaceScene) i do this :

```
[self unschedule:@selector(randomsActions:)] ; //stop timer
    [self unschedule:@selector(contact:)] ; //stop timer
    [self unschedule:@selector(contact:)] ; //stop timer
```

but it crashes.(i have seen people saying i do not have to unschedule them? )

so i tried this in my **dealloc** :

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleAllSelectorsForTarget: self];
```

which crash it also at the second time( crashes in class: CCScheduler.m )

in my dealloc i put also this:( DO I NEED TO??? )

> delete  _contactListener;
>     [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:
>   YES];
>   delete world;
>   world = NULL;
>   [super dealloc];

whats happen here ?
can someone give me any idea on what should be done in dealloc when replacing scenes?
what should i do with my timers ???

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you replace the scene, COCOS2d automatically dealloc all the scheduler you have started for the particular scene or layer.  Thats why you wrote [self scheduler:...];. 
Cocos2d Scheduler is somewhat different than NSTimer.

You do not need to dealloc the sccheduler just keep it blank, need not to worry,

```
- (void)dealloc {

    //memory deallocation  
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: my main problem was that it  crashes when i am trying to go back from menu to game scene. and it crashes on : -(void) update: (ccTime) dt method ,in the CCScheduler.m class. why is that ? is it something that relates to the timers ?

Comment: CCScheduler is also being used by internal mechanism of the cocos2d. like touch event etc. make sure you are not doing something wrong way in other parts.